# Solving the transport PDE equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

Consider the nonuniform transport equation
$$ u_t + (x^2 - 1) u_x = 0 $$
with initial condition  $ u(0, x) = f(x)= e^{-x^2} $

I need to show that the solution is

$$
u(t, x) = \exp\left( -\left(\frac{x + 1 + (x - 1) e^{-2t}}{x + 1 - (x - 1) e^{-2t}}\right)^2 \right)
$$
In this case, the characteristic curves are the solutions to
$
\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2 - 1,
$
and by seperation of variables we get the  equation
$
\beta(x) =  \frac{1}{2} \log \left( \frac{x(t)-1}{x(t)+1} \right) = t +k
$

I could not figure out how to proceed. I thought $ u(x,t) = f(\beta(x) -t) $
but this does not lead me to the desired result.

Comment: You need to solve for $x(t)$ be exponentiating the identity involving $\log$ that you have. Write
$$\frac{x(t) - 1}{x(t) + 1} = 1 - \frac{2}{x(t) + 1}$$

Comment: And if I compute  x as a function t, namely the inverse of $ \beta $ - what do I do next ?

Comment: I do not know what 'desperation of variables' is, but why not just solve the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2−1$? It is a separable equation that can be solves using integration.